# Flyway unable to find location and load sql scripts

Tags: java, mysql, spring-boot, flyway

After launching an application written in spring boot, the sql scripts do not load into the database.

Only an empty table named `flyway_schema_history` is created in the database.

[image: empty table: flyway_schema_history]

The path given to the scripts is as follows: **resources/db.migration**[image: path in project]

An example script named **V1__create_invoice.sql** looks like this:

```
create table invoice
(
    id          bigint        not null auto_increment PRIMARY KEY,
    name        varchar(255)  not null,
    price       decimal(9, 2) not null,
);
```

In the IntelliJ console, I get such information about the database or flyway: [image: logs]

This is how flyway configuration files are defined:

```
spring.flyway.baselineOnMigrate=true
spring.flyway.locations=classpath:resources/db/migration
spring.flyway.enabled=true
```

This is how the files to connect to the database are defined:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://${DATABASE_URL:localhost}:${DATABASE_PORT:3306}/${DATABASE_NAME:public}?useUnicode=true&serverTimezone=UTC
spring.datasource.username=${DATABASE_USERNAME:root}
spring.datasource.password=${DATABASE_PASSWORD:password}
```

I've tried changing the path to the scripts folder several times, for example like this
`classpath:db/migration` or `classpath:db.migration` but it didn't change anything.

Comment: Maybe it is a problem with the naming of the migration scripts have you tried to adhere explicitly to this Schema: V1_1_0__my_first_migration.sql

Comment: According to official docs example also the location does may not need the resources as first part but something like classpath:db/migration should be enough https://flywaydb.org/documentation/concepts/migrations.html#naming

Comment: That’s because everything below resources is put into classpath root.

Comment: If nothing helps it might be a good idea to set a breakpoint in the flyway spring boot starter and debug it during application startup. 

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/main/spring-boot-project/spring-boot-autoconfigure/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/flyway/FlywayAutoConfiguration.java 

You can find it in IntelliJ under the dependencies section.

Comment: @K3v1n0X90 Hi, thanks for the answer I changed the file names and unfortunately it didn't change anything, I also tried to debug it, but here I don't know too much where to set the breakpoint and what in total I should check in it.